# Combobox on userform populating only after cancelling first attempt

Tags: excel, combobox, userform, vba

I have a piece of code in a module:

```
UserForm1.Show
UserForm1.ComboBox1.clear
UserForm1.ComboBox2.clear
UserForm1.ComboBox1.List = Array("xxxxxxx", "xfdshthr", "tyetrert")
```

The user runs this code to bring up a userform with 2 comboboxes, the second of which needs to be cleared after the user has entered a new value in the first.

Bizarrely when I run this script, the first combobox doesn't populate so I click the cancel button on the form (`unload me`) and run the code above again. This time the combobox populates as expected. This happens every time.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you run the wrong procedure:

Populating a combobox/listbox in a userform has to de done when loading the userform. The preferred event for that is Userform_Initialize.
So fill that event in design mode:

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
  combobox1.list=array("aaa","bbb","ccc")
End Sub
```

After having done so the command 'Userform1.show' will automatically run the event-code and populate the combobox.